# How do I add a license pane to a MonoMac/Xamarin generated installer pkg?

Tags: macos, xamarin, monomac

In Xamarin Studio, under Options>Mac OSX Packaging for a MonoMac(or Xamarin.Mac) project, one can select "Create installer package." Further, on the "Advanced" tab, one can direct the build routine to a Product Definition, usually called something like `distribution.xml` which contains more information for customization, such as background image, license file, welcome, readme, etc etc etc.

No matter what example I work from, I cannot seem to put anything useful in `distribution.xml` which doesn't result in the build error

```
productbuild: error: Product definition plist "/Users/alexw/Development/My Company/myapp/src/MacClient/distribution.xml" is not valid.
```

Does anyone have a functional, working example of how to simply add a license into a generated pkg with MonoMac?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) with the **bundle .app file** after the building is completed.

This means that you will leave Xamarin Studio when building the installer, but if you want to customize installer process as above problem, this would be helpful.

More details about Packages with Xamarin.Mac in another answer [Bundle Multiple Xamarin apps in one pkg installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720490/bundle-multiple-xamarin-apps-in-one-pkg-installer/32925445#32925445)