# Bundle Multiple Xamarin apps in one pkg installer

Tags: macos, xamarin, installation, monomac, xamarin.mac

I have few Xamarin apps and I want to bundle them all as a single pkg/installer and organize them into a folder under Applications similar to the following snapshot attached. Is there an option to specify additional Xamarin apps in the bundle settings of the project or any build script needs to be written? Can anybody point to some samples ?

Thanks,

Suma.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### 1. pkg installer: [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html)

See **Payload** section to add folder and your .app files. [image]

They also support **Certification** for signing Developer Installer and **Commandline**. Just check the documentation.

### 2. Automation Build script:

Use [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create **.pkgproj file** that config your bundle apps

Go **Xamarin Studio -> Project Options -> Custom Command -> Add new Common After Build**: add script to copy all bundle apps to a folder that configured by above **.pkgproj file**

Run command line **packagesbuild** of [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to build the **.pkgproj file**

Finish. Get your .pkg installer file in Build folder.